# Is there a way to cluster 1Hz sensor data obtained from vehicles of different make and type to perform predictive maintenance?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I'm working on dataset containing 1Hz sensor data from 40 different channels from Vehicles. The vehicles are of different make and type. These vehicles experience common faults such as Injector Fault, Transmission fault etc. Is there a way to cluster the vehicles based on their sensor data patterns?

Answer (score 0):

You will have plenty of noise in your data set: most of your data points will not be relevant.

Preprocessing the data and extracting adequate features for your problem is key. You cannot expect this to work unsupervised.